# Segmentation Fault Error On Basic Array Operation

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

The following code is throwing `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error when I run it. The code is compiled with g++

```
struct SomeClass {
    int *available;
    int **need;
    int **allocation;
}

SomeClass::SomeClass(int nR, int nT) {
    available = new int[nR];
    for (int i = 0; i < nR; i++) {
        available[i] = 1;
    }

    *allocation = new int[nT];
    *need = new int[nT];
    for (int i = 0; i < nT; i++) {
        allocation[i] = new int[nR];
        need[i] = new int[nR];
        for (int j = 0; j < nR; j++) {
            allocation[i][j] = 0;
            need[i][j] = 1; // should equal 1
        }
    }
}
```

Am I sure that this code is generating the error? YES! Because I commented it out and everything works fine.

I checked this question:
[A segmentation fault error with 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556242/a-segmentation-fault-error-with-2d-array)

The answer says to set the stack size `ulimit -s unlimited`... But that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: This trows an error when you compile it or when you run it?

Comment: You are doing `*allocation`. Have you allocated something?

Comment: @Hogan  when I run it

Comment: Another ill-construed attempt to 2-dimensional arrays...

Comment: @SergeyA I'm still a noob in Cpp. excuse my poor attempt

Comment: the title is interesting... is this "basic array operation"?  Maybe it was 30 years ago.

Comment: @rz3r0, do not do this. Period. Do not emulate 2-D array with a pointer to pointer. Just use single-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @SergeyA I'm a Java programmer. So yeah maybe you're right..

Comment: @rz3r0 I am right. Trust me.

Comment: I think it's also important to note that it is better to use a 1D array not just because it's error-prone to simulate with a pointer to pointer, but also because of data locality. A 1D array has contiguous storage (guaranteed), so in performance critical code the number of cache missed will be significantly lower than when addressing via a pointer to pointer (in which only the outer pointers are contiguous, but the segments of data each points to are not).

Answer (score 3):

Because your types are:

```
int **need;
int **allocation;
```

these lines:

```
*allocation = new int[nT]; // dereferencing uninitialized pointer
*need = new int[nT];
```

should be:

```
allocation = new int*[nT]; // proper allocation
need = new int*[nT];
```

Didn't you think you'd need elements of `int*` type for `allocation[i] = new int[nR];` to work?

Comment: `*allocation = new int[nT];` is still syntactically correct, as it allocates memory for the first `int*` pointer in `allocation` (of course without having memory allocated for `allocation[0]` itself). But probably the OP wants what you mentioned.

Comment: @vsoftco, no it is both technically and practically incorrect.

Comment: @vsoftco -- it is a null point error since it is putting something in a place that does not exist yet.

Comment: Yes, you are right, that's why I replaced "technically correct" with "syntactically correct"

Comment: @rz3r0 I practically explained everything, do you want me to elaborate some part?

Comment: @LogicStuff no that was before you made your edits. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest (and strongly feel deja vu) to move away from an attempt to emulate 2-D arrays with pointers to pointers. It is hard to do this right. Pack all your values into single-dimensional array.

Comment: It's not just hard to get right, it's a silent performance killer. Sergey already knows this so I'm directing this at other readers. Rather than one contiguous memory block that is cache-friendly and predictable, a dynamic array of dynamic arrays is N+1  blocks of memory scattered across your memory space. You can't get a decent contiguous read, so the number of cache misses goes up and your program sits idle waiting on memory it could have already cached. In extreme cases, it might start thrashing, loading and unloading the same blocks over and over.